# listparindent in enumitem

Tags: enumitem

When using enumitem, I have encountered the following problem

```
\begin{itemize}[leftmargin = *,listparindent =1cm]
\item A.\\    aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa.
\end{itemize}
```

But there is not indentation for the first line of paragraph 'aaaa...'.
I have seen several times `listparindent = \parindent` but in my document I have `\setlength{\parindent}{0cm}`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`\\` does not end a paragraph, it just breaks the line.  Either insert a blank line or use `\par`:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}[leftmargin = *,listparindent =1cm]
\item A.\\
  aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaa
  aaaaaa a aaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaa aaa aaaaaaaaa aaa aa a aaaaaaaa
  aaaaaaaaa aa aaaaaa aaaaaaaa aaaaaaaa a aaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaa
  aaaaaaaaaaaaaa. 
\item B.

  aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaa
  aaaaaa a aaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaa aaa aaaaaaaaa aaa aa a aaaaaaaa
  aaaaaaaaa aa aaaaaa aaaaaaaa aaaaaaaa a aaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaa
  aaaaaaaaaaaaaa. 
\end{document}
```